# catoptions causes option clash with xcolor

Tags: color, option-clash

Look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my1.sty}
   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
   \RequirePackage{catoptions}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my2.sty}
   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{my1}
\usepackage{my2}

\begin{document}
   \rule{2cm}{2cm}
\end{document}
```

`catoptions` seems to cause an option clash if there is a `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` somewhere after it. Everything works fine if I load `my2` before `my1` but I can’t ensure that this won’t happen.

`my1` is a place holder for my `menukeys` package, `my2` is a place holder for any other package requiring `xcolor`.

Comment: From [catoptions guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/catoptions/catoptions-guide.pdf): "Packages that redefine
LaTeX's native options processing internals may not work properly with catoptions package. I know that
xcolor package redefines `\@declareoption` and the catoptions package has taken that fact into account,
but there may be other packages that modify LaTeX's options processing internals that I am not aware of." -- not that this is a real answer, but it may point someone toward a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an option clash for *xcolor* package in your code. It is easy to see that in your two (actually three) loading rounds of *xcolor*. Here is the error help:

```
? h
The package 'xcolor' has already been loaded with options:
  [cmyk].
There has now been an attempt to load it with no options. 
Adding the global options:
  'cmyk'
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

The *catoptions* redefines the LaTeX command `\@onefilewithoptions` to catch this type of situation. If you don't want it, then I would have to send you a patch. I will then create an option in *catoptions* to make strick option checking optional. However, I will be reluctant to do that. This is because the following definition by LaTeX isn't robust: when `#2` is empty, nothing happens (LaTeX's `\@for` cannot process empty list).

```
\def\@if@pti@ns#1#2{%
  \let\reserved@a\@firstoftwo
  \@for\reserved@b:=#2\do{%
    \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\expandafter,\reserved@b,}{,#1,}%
    \ifin@\else\let\reserved@a\@secondoftwo\fi}%
  \reserved@a
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I fear I don’t understand what you mean. I had a look at `source2e` but I can’t figure out what `\@onefilewithoptions` does. Could you explain it, please? Is you suggestion to solve my clash to use the global options to set `cmyk`?

Comment: You first loaded *xcolor* with option *cmyk* and later without any option. That leads to an option clash that LaTeX can't catch. The *catoptions* package highlights it. One way out is to be consistent with option loading. Another one is to allow the user of your package to load *xcolor*, or allow him/her to pass options to *xcolor*. Modifying the strict option check by *catoptions* isn't the solution, as in reality all option clashes should be indicated. You can use *catoptions*'s `\AfterProcessOptions` to load *xcolor* outside the options section (of your package) with the user's options.

Comment: OK, thanks again! I think I’m happy with the global options way :-) and just mention this in the manual for other users, since there are some packages that clash like this ...

Comment: @Tobi: Well I would wish you would drop `catoptions`. Loading babel twice after the package gives errors, using e.g. `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{graphicx}` gives option clash errors. I had to load `menukeys` in `\AtEndPreamble` to keep catoptions silent - and this is not something I want to explain to my customers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: At the moment it seems like I need `catoptions` but I plan a new implementation with LaTeX3 and hope that this makes `catoptions` superfluous for my package. At the moment we must live with these crude behavior `:-(` Sorry `;-)` (PS: If you have further suggestions your welcome to send an e-mail (mail@tweh.de, in german or english `;-)`) or use the GitHub repo (https://github.com/tweh/menukeys, in english) …)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thank you. I will modify catoptions in this regard.

Comment: @Tobi I second Ulrike Fisher's comment: I wish you'd drop `catoptions` too.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Can you estimate when a fixed version of `catoptions` will become available? BTW: The clsguide (offered by the LaTeX2e team) clearly says "If a package is always loaded with \RequirePackage... or \usepackage then, even if its loading is requested several times,  it will be loaded only once."

Comment: Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/40/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to delay the loading of `catoptions` with `etoolbox`’ `\AtEndPreamble` but this doesn’t wokr in the real world since I need some functions of `catoptions` in `my1` (i.e. `menukeys`)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my1.sty}
   \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
   \AtEndPreamble{\RequirePackage{catoptions}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my2.sty}
   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{my2}
\usepackage{my1}
\usepackage{my2}

\begin{document}
   \rule{2cm}{2cm}
\end{document}
```