# Did I misunderstand \RequirePackage? I don’t understand an option clash

Tags: packages, package-options, option-clash

Have a look at the following example, please.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.sty}
   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage{my}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
   Content
\end{document}
```

I expect this to compile, but it reports an option clash. I thought there could be only an option clash if I try to load a package with *different* options and that there's no clash if the package is loaded multiple times and *one* time with options. Is that wrong?

I know that I could fix this by changing the order of `my` and `xcolor` but I can think about cases where I can’t influence the order (e.g. `my` is loaded internally by the document class).

I found [\RequirePackage without option clashes because of the package loading order?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/requirepackage-without-option-clashes-because-of-the-package-loading-order) where Herbert gave the solution to split the package loading, which won’t work in my case. And I asked [catoptions causes option clash with xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45818/captions-causes-option-clash-with-xcolor), which is possibly a duplicate, a few minutes ago …

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `LaTeX2e` kernel defines `usepackage` to be exactly the same as `RequirePackage` in the `ltclass.dtx`.

```
    \if@compatibility\else\let\usepackage\RequirePackage\fi
```

So the fact that you use `RequirePackage` makes no difference and you still get an error.  If the same package is *requested* more than
once, nothing happens, unless the package has been requested with options that
were not given the first time it was loaded, in which case an error is produced.

Comment: Thanks. I kown that `\usepackage` uses `\RequirePackage` but I thought that no options won’t cause problems. So did I get you right that there’s no better work around than changing the order of loading packages?

Comment: @Tobi Unfortunately yes, unless you write your own routine to check if the package is present and then ignore errors. In general though is best to see the clashes.

Comment: Thanks again. [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45818/4918) Ahmed quotes the error help for the clash which suggests to use global options instead.

Answer (score 4):

In the above [linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45818/4918) question Ahmed Musa quotes the LaTeX error help on an option clash:

```
? h
The package 'xcolor' has already been loaded with options:
  [cmyk].
There has now been an attempt to load it with no options. 
Adding the global options:
  'cmyk'
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

It solves my problem if I set the options for `xcolor` via `\documentclass`

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage{my}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another trick is to use \PassOptionsToPackage to pass the option to the package.

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, I know, thanks. But I don’t like it because it seems inconvenient for me. Are the any pros or cons in preferring the global option way?

Comment: Well, if you wanted to pass `draft` option to one package and `final` option to another, your way wouldn't work…

Comment: @Seamus. Ahh … I didn’t think on that case :-)