# Is it ok to load a package twice (as long as no extra options are given)?

Tags: errors, packages, option-clash

In

[Loading package twice with \RequirePackage causes "option clash"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/loading-package-twice-with-requirepackage-causes-option-clash)

and

[Loading a package more than once](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/loading-a-package-more-than-once)

we see that a package can be loaded multiple times, as long as no options or no different options are given.

However, my question is not if this actually works, or if it is implemented in LaTeX this way (well, obviously it is), but if this is a *documented* behaviour.

This is what I've found in the `clsguide` about it:

"If a package is always loaded with
`\RequirePackage...`
or
`\usepackage`
then,
even if its loading is requested several times,  it will be loaded only once."

While this is a clear indication for me that loading a package several times is ok, the author of the `catoptions` has a different opinion:

"You first loaded `xcolor` with option `cmyk` and later without any option. That leads to an option clash that LaTeX can't catch. The `catoptions` package highlights it."
(Source: [catoptions causes option clash with xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45818/catoptions-causes-option-clash-with-xcolor#comment94051_45830) )

Any more hints from the LaTeX2e documentation regarding this issue?

Example documents which show the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[balancingshow]{multicol}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

All these examples compile fine without using `catoptions`, but fail when using it.

Comment: If you load a package with options and then reload it with no option, nothing happens; it's an error to do the converse or to load the package twice with different sets of options.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your quote from catoptions is about loading with different options. This naturally doesn't work. So where do you see a "different opinion"?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `xcolor` was loaded with options "cmyk" first and then loaded again without options. As long as you don't load the `catoptions` package additionally this works fine, so I don't see why your opinion is "This naturally doesn't work". It works, but is this indended?

Comment: so the answer seems to be yes, if you are using the standard package loader, but as with any latex macro if you load a package that redefines the internals, then the answer depends on that package.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As package author I need something I can rely on, "it depends" does not help me... It's easy to write a package which changes internal behaviour and blame other packages afterwards. Is this a bug in `catoptions` or not? What is the *documented* behaviour?

Comment: how can you rely on anything in a system when any package can redefine any part of the system? I'd say it's less than ideal behaviour but if the package documents what it does then it isn't really a bug as such. The latex core can only document what the core code does and as implemented, if the later call to \usepackage uses a (possibly empty) subset of the options used in the first call, the file is not input again, and no warning is given.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt This is clearly a deliberate decision of the design of `catoptions`: it's author feels that `\usepackage[foo]{bar}\usepackage{bar}` is an option clash. In contrast, the kernel team decided that this was not a clash. Both positions have points in their favour.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I don't see how "changing package loading from the documented behaviour  (and documenting the new behaviour)" is any different in principle from "changing `\caption` from the documented behaviour (and documenting the new behaviour)" That is one of the strengths of latex, that it can be extended. It is also one of its weaknesses, that extensions can interfere with each other. I think catoptions would be better not to do this, but I wouldn't call it a bug if it does.

Comment: @JosephWright So it's a question about feeling!? I can live with that. My feeling is that writing `\RequirePackage{caption}` within `subcaption` is totally fine, and the user has to decide if his feelings are more in sync with my feelings or the feelings of the `catoptions` package author ;-) When answering issues to users, can I quote this as the official point of view of the LaTeX team? :-D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see two differences between `catoptions` and `caption` regarding patching existing commands: 1. The package loading stuff is elementary for other packages and therefore affecting package authors. 2. There is IMHO no technical reason to change it the way `catoptions` does. As Joseph has already written: It's just about "feeling", the `catoptions` author "feels" that this is an option clash which the LaTeX2e team (and I) does "feel" not.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Sorry I hadn't understand that your question is about the order and the way catoptions changes the handling. I personally avoid to use catoptions and other packages of the author. He tries to much to do everything better without caring enough about side-effects on the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

#### Experiment 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Terminal output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./exp.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
No file exp.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./exp.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on exp.pdf (1 page, 9748 bytes).
Transcript written on exp.log.
```

#### Experiment 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Same terminal output.

#### Experiment 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

#### Experiment 4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Error as in experiment 3.

#### Comments

The `catoptions` package changes the definition of `\@fileswith@ptions`, which is internally used by `\usepackage` (and `\RequirePackage`).

Without it, the statement in the manual about package loading is true: loading a package with different sets of options raises an error, unless the second (or further) call is with a subset of the original set of options (for example no option) in the first call.

Comment: I know the outcome, that's not what I have asked about. Let's focus on Experiment 4: Is this a bug in `catoptions` (which should be fixed) or is `catoptions` merely highlighting a problem here?

Comment: @touhami Yes, of course. I'll fix.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt It's a misfeature of `catoptions`, yes: it changes the behavior of `\usepackage` making illegal what should be legal. And, no, there is no problem to be highlighted, except that `catoptions` should be modified.

Comment: I think @AxelSommerfeldt is asking what exactly the *bad idea* in the `catoptions` is and whether there is a way to signal the user about multiple calls to the his own package

Comment: @percusse `catoptions.sty` is quite complex. It fails in doing the right thing, where it does is the author's business.

Comment: @percusse First of all I try to find out if the author of `catoptions` is wrong or if I am wrong. (I know this isn't easy to answer, but otherwise I would not ask here ;-)) Second, what do I tell the user? The user has a document class which loads `caption` and `catoptions`, and the user tries to load `subcaption` additionally and get an error message (because of  `\RequirePackage{caption}` inside `subcaption`). I told the user the problem is in `catoptions` and the `catoption` author told the user that it's a option clash and his package is only highlighting an existing problem here. :-(

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I'm just trying to reformulate the question because it sounds very interesting to know. But it seems to me that if you remove the author opinions and put the MWE I think people can chime in with more specific details where exactly catoptions fails to operate. Apparently there is a context for your question and you are pretty capable of TeX hence I think it would be beneficial for all of us if the question is steered towards the experts rather than package loading multiple times detail itself.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt The only existing problem is that the author of `catoptions` was not able to make his modified version of `\usepackage` to work as it should. There is no problem in the LaTeX kernel, as it behaves as documented; of course the option parsing could be improved, but certainly not in a way that invalidates existing documents.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt if I wasn't on the latex team I think I'd have no problem in saying catoptions is wrong here. But as I am, I can't really do that unless I can formulate a rule that says what parts of the latex format a package can change, and I don't want to do that. If it was a general package and it changed the package loading for all packages as an accidental side effect, then I'd say it is clearly wrong, but since the first line of the package documentation says it redefines the latex package loading, it's a grey area.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your dilemma,but on the one hand there is "We consider it good practice,when writing packages and classes,to use LATEX commands as much as possible" and "We recommend strongly that you use them (=`\RequirePackage` and others),rather than the primitive `\input` command,for a number of reasons" inside the `clsguide`,and on the other hand you say I cannot rely on anything because everything of LaTeX could be changed. So either maintaining packages is doomed to fail or I have to rewrite my sty using as much TeX primitives as possible, to minimize problems with other packages!?

Comment: Maybe we could agree on "Since this is a documented behavior of `catoptions` it's not a bug, but since other package authors rely on the documented behavior of basic LaTeX commands it's a bad idea"?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Indeed, I talked about a “misfeature”.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt yes  :-)...