# Option clash for textcomp with newtxtext, minted and xwatermark

Tags: minted, newtx, option-clash, xwatermark

I am having an option clash for package `textcomp`, it happens with this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xwatermark}

\begin{document}
    Hi
\end{document}
```

But only happens when those 3 packages are together, there is no problem if one is missing i.e., `newtxtext` + `minted`, `minted` + `xwatermark` or `newtxtext` + `xwatermark` works fine, but `newtxtext` + `minted` + `xwatermark` generates the error.

I tried adding `\PreventPackageFromLoading{textcomp}` before `newtxtext`, and it indeed work, but I don't know if this is affecting something in the background that I am not aware of. Anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, i tried adding [notextcomp] option to all three packages, but non of them accepte it, also, i think that would be the same effect that \PreventPackageFromLoading{textcomp} does, right?

Comment: Don't use the xwatermark package. It (or more precisely the catoptions packages it loads) does curious things with the option list handling and is rather a pain. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45818/2388 which is a similar problem.